# Issue with linking Pods in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, package, native

I have been trying for the last days now to get React-Native (tried 0.49-0.53) to work with several native Modules/Packages like *react-native-image-resizer, react-native-orientation, react-native-splash-screen, HockeySDK etc.*

When I install the packages according to the package Maintainer/git repo README, there is always a link error - some file missing unless I also install Pods:

`$pod install`

This leads to installing the packages Podfiles, but also the React Pod is installed, unfortunately an outdated version (0.11).

To install a current version, I followed this React Native tutorial https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#configuring-cocoapods-dependencies .

Also I need to change the Xcode-Project from *.xcodeproject* to *.xcworkspace* (According to several github issues, please write if you are interested, I can regoogle the links).

This helps with the errors before but leads to this error:
`ld: 21 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64`

So the problem is that 2 versions of React are deployed simultaneously?

So wrapping it up:

- Packages with native implementation need to be linked (`react-native link`)
- Linking them installs Pods which in turn reinstalls/links React as Pod
- This leads to a * duplicate symbols* error

Any idea?

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I re-initialized a new project not installing pods at all!

Also be careful, most npm-packages require either normal installation or pods, **just don't use pods!**

The problem is just it will link a whole extra react-native as a pod, sometimes even a different version, which in the end leads to duplicate symbols. Maybe one could reference the react native libs to the already installed (in node_modules), but 1. I don't know how and 2. found the above way.

Comment: Commenting on the -1 downvote:
Sorry for the answer but no pods at all seemed the best solution, following the "as simple as possible, as complicated as needed" thinking. Also there are no limitations with this approach. Regards